# How to include R.java in a custom android build?

Tags: java, android, r.java-file, custom-build

I'm trying to add an application to a custom android build, but it is unable to understand resources like Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and colorPrimary and colorAccent, which leads me to believe it is having trouble reading and building R.java.

### My Error

```
target R.java/Manifest.java: MyApplication21 (out/target/common/obj/APPS/MyApplication21_intermediates/src/R.stamp)
packages/apps/MyApplication21/res/values/styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

packages/apps/MyApplication21/res/values/styles.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.

packages/apps/MyApplication21/res/values/styles.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.

packages/apps/MyApplication21/res/values/styles.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.

build/core/package_internal.mk:236: recipe for target 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/MyApplication21_intermediates/src/R.stamp' failed
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/MyApplication21_intermediates/src/R.stamp] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/mkemp/android'

#### make failed to build some targets  ####
```

### What I did:

1. Created an android app. This app compiles in android studio.
2. Copied the manifest, java (renamed src), and res directories into my custom build: `android/packages/apps/MyApplication21`
3. Created an Android.mk file

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

   # Java sources are in src
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

   # Resources are in res
   LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

   # These jars are needed
   LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v7-appcompat \
   android-support-v4 

   # The name of this application
   LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApplication21

   # No proguard
   LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
   ```

So far I have resolved errors that include not being able to understand Java classes like ActionBarActivity and TaskStackBuilder by including `android-support-v7-appcompat` and `android-support-v4` in that order, into the Android.mk file, but I have no idea what Java library I should call in order to generate an R.java file.

Can anyone help?

Edit:

I notice that an R.stamp file is not being created in `android/out/target/common/obj/APPS/MyApplication21/src`, which should be built there judging by the other apps in the APPS folder ... and again leads me to believe the culprit is the R.java file not being generated correctly.

Comment: are you compiling native and jni code?

Comment: @nandsito no, just java. I am able to build my app by removing all references to the four variables in the error messages, but I don't want a blank app with no theme unless that is the only way I can get it to run.

Comment: i'm not sure if you need an Android.mk file since you're not compiling native code, but i'm not familiar with building a custom android